# What is meant by " analytic set "?

Tags: set-theory, terminology, definition, borel-sets

I am a beginner with set theory.

What is meant by " analytic set " ?

I see this term in the context of set theory, calculus and real analysis but I have no idea what it means.

See here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set

where it occurs in the non-Borel set part.

Comment: Ref: Measure Theory by Cohen.

Comment: My confusion makes all found definitions of related things seems circular ...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set

Comment: @jjagmath I found that confusing sorry. BUT thanks for adding anyway

Comment: There are several equivalent definitions. I think that the simplest is "A set is analytic if it's the continuous image of a Borel set"

Comment: @jjagmath +1 but why is that not called a continuous set then ?

Comment: @mick for the same reason a giraffe is not called a neckbeast.

Comment: euh............

Answer (score 2):

At the first you should know about Polish space; by knowing topology and having a general knowledge about it, we can explain like this:

**polish space** is a separable completely metrizable topological space; that is, a space homeomorphic to a complete metric space that has a countable dense subset.

Common examples of Polish spaces are the **real line**, **any separable Banach space**, **the Cantor space**, and **the Baire space**.

Now we can say,
subset of a Polish space **$X$** is an analytical set if it is a continuous image of a Polish space.
for giving you more information I will link Wikipedia and Youtube.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set

https://youtu.be/xX7ORlPu5xE?si=6C1yqGGNPnrsW8sN